# How can I make floating header columns to scroll horizontally and prevent them to align left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a html table that always shows its header columns, when the user scrolls the windows. It works fine, but the header (thead) is always aligned left; when the table is narrow and centered, the columns don't match anymore the header columns. This also happens when the table is very wide and has many columns, forcing the horizontal scroll to appear; the header doesn't scroll, and always the first columns are displayed.

JavaScript:

```
function moveScroll(){
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var anchor_top = $("#main_table").offset().top;
var anchor_bottom = $("#bottom_anchor").offset().top;
if (scroll > anchor_top && scroll < anchor_bottom)
{
    clone_table = $("#clone");
    if(clone_table.length == 0)
    {
        clone_table = $("#main_table").clone();
        clone_table.attr('id', 'clone');
        clone_table.css({position:'fixed', 'pointer-events': 'none', top: 0});
        clone_table.width($("#main_table").width());
        $("#table_container").append(clone_table);
        $("#clone").css({visibility:'hidden'});
        $("#clone thead").css({visibility:'visible'});
    }
}
else
{
    $("#clone").remove();
}
}
$("#main_table").wrap('<div id="table_container"></div>');
$('<div id="bottom_anchor"></div>').insertAfter('#main_table');
$(window).scroll(moveScroll);
```

HTML:

```
<table id="main_table" align="center">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>Column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>Column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 500px;
}
thead tr {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Preview [horizontal scroll problem](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaUU/19/)

Preview [narrow centered table](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaUU/4/) - solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/AvaUU/7/

Add in:

```
.css({
    position: 'fixed',
    'pointer-events': 'none',
    left: $("#main_table").offset().left+'px',
    top: 0
})
```

(Oh, and I chained a lot of your jQuery together, just because I like how that looks.)

Comment: Thanks! This solved the centered table problem. But not the one width the horizontal scroll. Can you check this please? I'm not a jQuery expert. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaUU/19/)

Comment: Thank you. It solved the horizontal scroll issue, but it broke the centered table thing.. I will try to find a solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is it possible to also make the first column behave like this? So that the first row (column headers) and the first column should always be visible? Thanks....

Comment: It's probably possible; I've never worried about it before because there are plugins to do it for you -- http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html is the most popular.

Comment: I've done it. [http://jsfiddle.net/AvaUU/35/](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaUU/35/). I found only iframe like solutions (with extra scrolls) in your suggestion . It's weird that that kind of fixed columns is available everywhere, while what I need seems to be hard to find.