# How to set auto margin for floating Div like GMail buttons menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div in my HTML page which I want to act like a floating menu after page scrolls up to certain pixels.

I tried this here http://jsfiddle.net/JnbQQ/1/

Problem is once the user scrolls up, the div looses its margin which is set to auto and moves to left corner of the page.

Can someone please help?

Comment: I dont know if you had that, but with a certain viewport height ( so that your if statement would just about activate ) it just went crazy after I scrolled.. It wanted to go back to the top no matter how much I scrolled. This was on mac Chrome 14.

Comment: Yes, this happens in IE as well. Trying to find out, why?

Comment: I found the answer to my original problem. As we can not set auto margin to a fixed position element we can put another div surrounding PageHeaderTextDiv div. And used this div in JS to make fixed and set its width to 100%. Thus the PageHeaderTextDiv sets to auto margin within this div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at jquery Waypoints plugin.

Site: 
http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/

Demo: 
http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/

Comment: Yes, This is the behavior I want on my page but just for this I do not want to use whole library. Hence trying to do the small java script myself.

Comment: @Maheep Your code isnt far from working.. but if you think about it this way.. Waypoints plugin is about the size of small jpg image.

Comment: A brilliant and elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use margin this time because of position: fixed. Instead, I recommend something like:

```
$('.PageHeaderTextDiv').css({
  position: 'fixed',
  top: '0',
  left: '50%'
});
```

You'll probably would have to work on it but you'll know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416462/how-can-i-make-floating-header-columns-to-scroll-horizontally-and-prevent-them-to) out. You can replace the `<table>` tags in that solution with divs